# Mocking non-virtual method generating errors

Tags: googlemock

I'm trying to get the hang of Google Mocks but I've hit a snag trying to mock non-virtual methods. I have a Socket class that I want to mock.  It has a non-virtual method called "write" that takes to arguments:

```
class Socket {
public:
    int write(const unsigned char* buffer, size_t bufferLength) const;
}
```

So I create a Mock class as specified cook book:

```
class MockSocket {
public:
    MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(write, int(const unsigned char* data, size_t dataLength));
};
```

But this doesn't compile. It generates the following errors:

```
error: size of array ‘this_method_does_not_take_0_arguments’ is negative
error: no matching function for call to ‘testing::internal::FunctionMocker<int ()(const unsigned char*, size_t)>::Invoke()’
error: no matching function for call to ‘testing::internal::FunctionMocker<int ()(const unsigned char*, size_t)>::With()’
```

Could someone tell me why??

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, didn't mix my coffee strong enough this morning.  Figured out the problem. Was using the wrong macro.  This works:

```
class MockSocket {
public:
    MOCK_CONST_METHOD2(foo, int(const unsigned char* buffer, size_t len));
};
```